# Calculate percentile of value in column

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, distribution

I have a dataframe with a column that has numerical values. This column is not well-approximated by a normal distribution. Given another numerical value, not in this column, how can I calculate its percentile in the column? That is, if the value is greater than 80% of the values in the column but less than the other 20%, it would be in the 20th percentile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the column, and see if the value is in the first 20% or whatever percentile.

for example:

```
def in_percentile(my_series, val, perc=0.2): 
    myList=sorted(my_series.values.tolist())
    l=len(myList)
    return val>myList[int(l*perc)]
```

Or, if you want the actual percentile simply use `searchsorted`:

```
my_series.values.searchsorted(val)/len(my_series)*100
```

Comment: This way I have to iterate over all possible percentiles to find out which percentile the new value is in.

Comment: Please be warned that using searchsorted() will not provide accurate results. I'm getting "100" for a value that is in the 94.5% percentile.

Answer (score 44):

To find the percentile of a value relative to an array (or in your case a dataframe column), use the scipy function `stats.percentileofscore()`.

For example, if we have a value `x` (the other numerical value not in the dataframe), and a reference array, `arr` (the column from the dataframe), we can find the percentile of `x` by:

```
from scipy import stats
percentile = stats.percentileofscore(arr, x)
```

Note that there is a third parameter to the `stats.percentileofscore()` function that has a significant impact on the resulting value of the percentile, viz. `kind`. You can choose from `rank`, `weak`, `strict`, and `mean`. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) for more information.

For an example of the difference:

```
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

>>> stats.percentileofscore(df['a'], 4, kind='rank')
80.0

>>> stats.percentileofscore(df['a'], 4, kind='weak')
80.0

>>> stats.percentileofscore(df['a'], 4, kind='strict')
60.0

>>> stats.percentileofscore(df['a'], 4, kind='mean')
70.0
```

As a final note, if you have a value that is greater than 80% of the other values in the column, it would be in the 80th percentile (see the example above for how the `kind` method affects this final score somewhat) not the 20th percentile. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Probably very late but still

```
df['column_name'].describe()
```

will give you the regular 25, 50 and 75 percentile with some additional data
but if you want percentiles for some specific values then

```
df['column_name'].describe(percentiles=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
```

This will give you 10th, 20th, 30th and 50th percentiles.
You can give as many values as you want.

The resulting object can be accessed like a dict:

```
desc = df['column_name'].describe(percentiles=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
print(desc)
print(desc['10%'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for values over/under a specific threshold, you could consider using pandas ***qcut*** function. If you wanted values under 20% and over 80%, divide your data into 5 equal sized partitions. Each partition would represent a 20% "chunk" of equal size (five 20% partitions is 100%). So, given a DataFrame with 1 column 'a' which represents the column you have data for:

```
df['newcol'] = pd.qcut(df['a'], 5, labels=False)
```

This will give you a new column to your DataFrame with each row having a value in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). Where 0 represents your lowest 20% and 4 represents your highest 20% which is the 80% percentile.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to divide percentile by 100 and call it quantile:

```
result = my_series.quantile(0.8)
```